# Can not find the ros-launch-OpenNI-launch package

Tags: kinect, asus-xtion-pro-live, ros-hydro, ubuntu, ubuntu-precise

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
I have problem, when I write on my terminal : sudo apt-get install ros-launch-openni-launch
I have this message : "Can not find the paquet ros-launch-openni-launch"

I have installed openni, Nite, Sensorkinect without problem, and i had follow the wiki ros to instal ros on linux 12.04.

What is the problem, and how can i resolve this?
thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/168436/can-not-find-the-ros-launch-openni-launch-package/) by [guigui](https://answers.ros.org/users/16871/guigui/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2014-05-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The package name are as such : ros-DISTRO-[package name] where distro is the distro you're using.

If you're using hydro, try `sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-openni-launch`

---

Originally posted by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) with karma: 1172 on 2014-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1